# Terminal doesn't work (bash commands aren't recognizable)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path, environment-variables

I have macOS Sierra version 10.12.6

I tried to add a path using the terminal. I entered `source ~/.bash_profile` and then a text file opened and I entered my path.

But then the terminal stopped responding and bash commands are not recognizable anymore.

If I enter: `source ~/.bash_profile` nothing happens.

And if I enter any environment related command an error message shows: `-bash: printenv: command not found`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably messed up your path.  When you're setting a path it's important to append to it rather than overwrite, or you lose access to all the system paths; `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/sbin` etc.  When setting a new path make sure you use:

```
$PATH=$PATH:/path/to/add
```

You can fix this by removing the line from `.bash_profile` where you overwrote the path.  Please paste the contents of `.bash_profile` if this does not work.

Comment: How can I remove the line from .bash_profile? I used to access it from {source ~/.bash_profile} but now I can't

Answer (score 0):

You've replaced $PATH with some of your values and you might not be able to update .bash_profile because of the unavailability of nano. Use the following command to access nano and environment variables.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

After using the command you can use `nano ~/.bash_profile` to fix the problem.